# Find out whether a user has a public or private profile on instagram using API?

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, instagram

I've done a fair bit of searching on the Instagram API docs and can't find a way to determine whether or not a user has a public or protected profile?

This also has to be done without an access_token.  I have a client_id to use.

Just for a bit of context, I'm just building a small practice app which reads a csv of usernames in PHP and then makes a call to the API to determine whether it is public or private.

Comment: Updated information here: [Instagram Basic Display API: How to check if user's Instagram account is public or private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644024/instagram-basic-display-api-how-to-check-if-users-instagram-account-is-public)

Answer (score 13):

Use the GET relationship endpoint.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/user-id/relationship
```

This endpoint returns a BOOL value "target_user_is_private".

Comment: This is very helpful to me. It's not mentioned at all in the documentation (which is pretty crap tbh). It seems [@Jon Hockley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1216535/jon-hockley)'s problem can't be solved without the use of an `access_token` though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [User Media](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_with_client_id) endpoint with client_id:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER_ID/media/recent/?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT_ID
```

If the user is private you will get a response like this:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APINotAllowedError","code":400,"error_message":"you cannot view this resource"}}
```

If the user is public, then you will get API response with `"code":200` with user recent media data - `"data":[...]`

Comment: you are using client_id so in this case it does not matter if u follow or not, the check is made without relation to a user