# Is it possible to determine if an Instagram account is private?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

With the updates to the Instagram API in November we can longer check if a user is private by calling the API with a Client Id.  All calls require an access token so this solution is no longer viable  [Find out whether a user has a public or private profile on instagram using API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101650/find-out-whether-a-user-has-a-public-or-private-profile-on-instagram-using-api)

I would like to be able to search for users but filter out private users or at the very least be able to tell if their account is private when using this call `api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=jack&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`.

I would also like to be able to search for tags and filter out the private media when using this call `api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

I have looked at all the endpoints and data that is returned and I can't see anything that would help me.  I even tried using the [oembed endpoint](https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/) thinking that it wouldn't return an embed if the post was private but it still does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instagram Basic Display API: How to check if user's Instagram account is public or private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644024/instagram-basic-display-api-how-to-check-if-users-instagram-account-is-public)