# Check if an Instagram account is public or private

Tags: json, api, instagram, instagram-api

I have looked this particular question: [Find out whether a user has a public or private profile on instagram using API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101650/find-out-whether-a-user-has-a-public-or-private-profile-on-instagram-using-api), but I don't see a return bool value `target_user_is_private` as mentioned in the above question. I also don't see any other way to check; none of the endpoints on https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/ seems to tell me if an account if private or not. Is there any way to check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This endpoint returns `target_user_is_private`

```
  https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

If you are in sandbox mode then you will not get a response with relationship for any user other than your sandbox approved user.

If you are in sandbox mode, add a user to your sandbox, and then use the above API with that user's {user-id}, you will get a response with `target_user_is_private`

Comment: I don't have the scope for follower_list. Is there any possible way you can think of that maybe allows me to search for only public accounts in a query, or any checks that I can do to make sure I'm only looking at public accounts?

Comment: Instagram API does allow you to see private accounts any more, if you can access any user account with API then it is public, u can use `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`, if this has error then it is private