# How to get notified when an instagram private user has been public?

Tags: api, instagram, private, public, notify

How to I get notification notified when an instagram private user has been public?

I have looked these particular questions, but still didn't see a way to get notified when a private user goes to public. Is there any way to get notification?

[Find out whether a user has a public or private profile on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101650/find-out-whether-a-user-has-a-public-or-private-profile-on-instagram-using-api)

[Check if an Instagram account is public or private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709552/check-if-an-instagram-account-is-public-or-private)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is: use the [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) to "ping" the users profile periodically.

However, as far as I'm aware, this is not a valid API use case. Short of the private user accepting a [Sandbox Invite](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) from you, I'd say there is no way this can happen. I don't imagine Instagram would want you to have this ability.

Second thought, I suppose you could build a web crawler that would check the users Instagram every day using the public internet. Just hit `https://instagram.com/{user's name}` and send yourself an email if the page has posts. If it's still private, do nothing, try again later.